# Can not retrieve FCM token in bare minimum React App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was having problems getting a token in my existing App,  so after a day of fighting with it and trying various solutions posted in old answers, I broke down and created a brand new app using:

```
npx create-react-app my-app2 --template pwa-typescript
```

I then installed the latest version of firebase using:

```
npm install firebase --save
```

Then added a few lines code to the generated App.tsx file, basted on this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).

The full code in App.tsx follows, I added some comments to what I added from the default.

running this results in this in the console:

I have tried with and with out an empty `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file at the project root.

> An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging:
> We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to
> register a ServiceWorker for scope
> ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with
> script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script
> has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
> (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
> at registerDefaultSw (registerDefaultSw.ts:43:1)
> at async updateSwReg (updateSwReg.ts:28:1)
> at async getToken$1 (getToken.ts:43:1)

I do see some mention of a service-worker trying to install as shown in the image below.
I feel I am missing something very simple.

[image: develper tools image]

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

// I added these two imports
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";


function App() {
  
  // begin added this code 
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "<my-key>",
    authDomain: "<my-project>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<my-project>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<my-project>",
    storageBucket: "<my-project>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<mysenderid>",
    appId: "<my-app-id>"
  };

  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
  getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: '<my-generated-vapidKey>' }).then((currentToken) => {
    if (currentToken) {
      // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
      // ...
    } else {
      // Show permission request UI
      console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      // ...
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    // ...
  });

  // end added code

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally stumbled on the solution to this issue.  While the firebase documentation says the empty `firebase-messaging-sw.js` needs to be in your app's root folder, it actually needs to be in the **public** folder.

Once I moved it there I was able to receive the token, and I now see the service worker activated and running in chrome developer tools.

[image]